# How to pass docker container arguments when running the image in a Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Dockerfile that ends with

```
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "index.js"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

The `index.js` can take a couple different arguments and I also need to expose a port for the container so if I run it manually I do something like:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 my_container:latest --arg1 somearg --arg2 anotherarg
```

How do I do this in a Jenkinsfile? My test will communicate with this container so it needs to be running before I run the test. I use `withRun()` get it running before the test runs but I don't see how to specify the `--arg1 somearg --arg2 anotherarg`

```
stage('TestMicroservice') {
    //
    // HOW DO I SPECIFY '--arg1 somearg --arg2 anotherarg'?
    //
    docker.image("my_container:latest").withRun('-p 3000:3000') {
        sh 'npm run test-microservice'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the second argument of withRun

```
.withRun('-p 3000:3000', '--arg1 somearg --arg2 anotherarg')
```

Comment: Perfect!!! I looked around for a long time trying to find a proper reference for this command and others. Do you know where I'd find that? How did you know about the second argument for withRun()?

Comment: I looked it up in issues https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33063

Comment: Maybe they should put the documentation in a more straight forward location.. Just sayin

Comment: There's like no documentation on this. Anyone find any?

Answer (score 5):

Use `.withRun('-p 3000:3000', '--arg1 arg1 --arg2 arg2')`. The documentation for this is in the docker-workflow-plugin [here](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html#docker-workflow).

Comment: I think the plugin docs are here now: https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/plugins/docker-workflow

Answer (score 3):

Another way you pass container arguments is by using the inside method. Below is an example taken from https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#caching-data-for-containers (click on the Toggle Scripted Pipeline link to view it)

```
node {
    /* Requires the Docker Pipeline plugin to be installed */
    docker.image('maven:3-alpine').inside('-v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2') {
        stage('Build') {
            sh 'mvn -B'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now how to do this using the declarative syntax?

Answer (score 1):

I leave this post because it was asked in a comment above:
The documentation for Docker Pipeline plugin can be accessed like this:

- Go to any Pipeline Job, and on the bottom click on the link [Pipeline Syntax]
- One the left menu choose Global variable Reference. The plugin has the docker variable (with supported methods)