# Jenkins Docker Declarative .withRun

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am using the declarative format for pipeline files and running inside of a docker container that is defined using a Dockerfile in my project's root directory.

My Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    dockerfile {
      additionalBuildArgs '--network host'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        sh 'pytest --version'
      }
    }
}
```

I would like to pass additional arguments to the docker run command similar to this question ... [How to pass docker container arguments when running the image in a Jenkinsfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46206215/how-to-pass-docker-container-arguments-when-running-the-image-in-a-jenkinsfile)

Is it possible to do that in the declarative pipeline format, or should I switch?

Edit:

This is essentially the equivalent of what I am trying to do in non-declarative:

```
node {
  def pytestImage = docker.build('pytest-image:latest', '--network host .')

  pytestImage.inside('--network=host') {
    sh 'pytest --version'
    // other commands ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `args` option to your `dockerfile`. It passes arguments directly to a `docker run` invocation:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    dockerfile {
      additionalBuildArgs '--network host'
      args '--network=host'
    }
  }

  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        sh 'pytest --version'
      }
    }
}
```

More information [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/)

Comment: I'm no longer using Jenkins but I think this should work! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a ton! I searched for ages for a way to pass run parameters to my container from Jenkins!